# Get String Between 2 Strings with Arduino

Tags: string, arduino

I am looking for a way to get a String between 2 Strings using Arduino. This is the source String:

```
Hello, my name is John Doe# and my favourite number is 32#.
```

The output has to be:

```
String name = "John Doe"; //Between "name is " and "#"
String favouriteNumber = "32"; //Between "number is " and "#"
```

**How can this be achieved with Arduino?**

I am not able to find any information online about this. Those examples for C are not working anyway. I understand that using String is not recommended in Arduino, but I have to do it this way to make things simpler.

By the way, this method of using a '#' to indicate the end of the data is not an ideal way to do it as I would like the input to be more human readable and more natural. **Would anyone please suggest another way to do this as well?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: >`but I have to do it this way to make things simpler.`  There's your mistake:In Arduino C, the `char*`strings are much more powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Function midString find the substring that is between two other strings "start" and "finish". If such a string does not exist, it returns "". A test code is included too.

```
void setup() {
  test();
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}

String midString(String str, String start, String finish){
  int locStart = str.indexOf(start);
  if (locStart==-1) return "";
  locStart += start.length();
  int locFinish = str.indexOf(finish, locStart);
  if (locFinish==-1) return "";
  return str.substring(locStart, locFinish);
}

void test(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  String str = "Get a substring of a String. The starting index is inclusive (the corresponding character is included in the substring), but the optional ending index is exclusive";
  Serial.print(">");
  Serial.print( midString( str, "substring", "String" ) );
  Serial.println("<");
  Serial.print(">");
  Serial.print( midString( str, "substring", "." ) );
  Serial.println("<");
  Serial.print(">");
  Serial.print( midString( str, "corresponding", "inclusive" ) );
  Serial.println("<");
  Serial.print(">");
  Serial.print( midString( str, "object", "inclusive" ) );
  Serial.println("<");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

just searched for this and saw no answer so i cooked one up.
i prefer working with String as well because of code readability and simplicity.
for me its more important than squeezing every last drop of juice out of my arduino.

```
String name = GetStringBetweenStrings("Hello, my name is John Doe# and my favourite number is 32#." ,"name is ","#");



String GetStringBetweenStrings(String input, String firstdel, String enddel){
      int posfrom = input.indexOf(firstdel) + firstdel.length();
      int posto   = input.indexOf(enddel);
      return input.substring(posfrom, posto);
}
```

watch out for the first case its fine, but for the second one you would have to change the second filter sting to "#." so it doesn't use the first occurrence of the #

Comment: This code will return an incorrect string if the desired substring does not exist. Also it does not work if both strings at each end are the same.